# Does anybody know what slideshow / jquery plugin is used on Mod X Cms?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

If  you go to their website here: www.modxcms.com, you will see the WHAT, WHY, HOW slideshow. Can anybody tell me what they are using to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [jQuery LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html). From their `pushup.js` (indented for clarity):

```
$('#whatwhyhow-questions').localScroll({
  target:'#whatwhyhow-answers'
});

$("#whatwhyhow-questions a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#whatwhyhow-arrow').animate({top:$(this).attr("rel")});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using a customized js file named pushup.js built on top of jQuery and there you can find the

animate function being used.